# :hover function not opening popup

Tags: html, css

I have created a basic popup window which opens when hovered over. However, I have been unable to get it to work so far. Below is one of the 5 parts of the popup windows I intend to create.

```css
#youtube-popup {
  display: none;
}

#youtube:hover + #youtube-popup {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
  <div class="messagepop pop">
    <div id="youtube-popup">
      <font size=5><b>Title</b>
    <br><font size=2>
  Text would go here.
    <br><font size=5><b>Title</b>
    <br><font size=2>More text would go here.
  </font></div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
          <br>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <div class="hover">
              <img href="" id="youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/yt/brand/media/image/YouTube-icon-dark.png" width="10%" height="10%" padding="1px 1px 1px 1px"></div>
            </li>
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work as when hovered over, text should appear next to the icon?

Also, is it possible to get the text to remain until another icon is hovered over?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could look like this:

```
document.getElementById('youtube').addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
   // set the display = "none" for all other popups
   // (not shown)

   // make the current popup visible
   document.getElementById('youtube-popup').style.display = "block";
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any Icons there int he markup but i have done the following Jquery

```
$('#youtube').mouseenter(function() {
$('#youtube-popup').removeClass('puffOut').addClass('puffIn magictime');
});

$('#youtube-popup').mouseleave(function() {
$(this).removeClass('puffIn').addClass('puffOut');
});
```

Link
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/YWaWJE

I am not exactly sure what you wanted, but let me know if this is not the exact solution

Answer (score 0):

It is about positioning.

For this to work just with CSS you have to put `#youtube-popup` directly after `#youtube`.

Here you can see example https://jsfiddle.net/dhgz02eL/

Your code is pretty messy so I changed it a bit. Closing tags were incorrect and you should use CSS font styling instead of `<font>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), which means you are trying to select elements who lie on the same level in the DOM.

However, that is not the case `#youtube` and `#youtube-popup` are not near each other, which makes it hard to solve with a CSS selector.

You can solve this with with either by changing your HTML or with Javascript. With HTML you have to put your entire `#youtube-popup` next to `#youtube` (inside `.hover`). With this solution you don't need to change your CSS.

If you want the text to remain, even after you have removed your mouse, you should defenitely use JavaScript.

Make use of the [onmouseover Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp). This even will be called when you move your mouse ON to the element or its children. To handle when the mouse LEAVES the elemnt or its children, see the [onmouseout Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp). It is not required in this case.

```
var youtube = document.querySelector('#youtube');

var popup = document.querySelector('#youtube-popup');

youtube.addEventListener('onmouseover', function(){//There are alternative syntax options

var otherPopup = document.querySelector('.otherpopup');
otherPopup.style.display = 'none'; //Disable previously opened popups

popup.style.display = 'inline';

});
```

The element will display even when you move your mouse away front the element, but you can handle those cases by something similar to what I wrote in the example.